# $2-$conformal vector fields on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

A vector field $\zeta$ is conformal on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ if $$\mathcal L_\zeta g=\rho g$$These vector fields have a well known geometrical interpretation. The flow of a conformal vector field consists of conformal transformations.
I want to enlarge this class of conformal vector fields as follows. A vector field $\zeta$ is $2-$conformal on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ if $$\mathcal L_\zeta \mathcal L_\zeta g=\rho g$$ It is clear that any conformal vector field is $2-$conformal and the converse need not be true. T. Operea, B. Unal and me  did the same think for $2-$Killing vector fields(see references blow).
**My question is:**
What could be the geometric interpretation of a $2-$conformal vector field? In fact, I want to understand the left-hand side, is it a double consequent dragging of $g$ or some thing else?
References
[$2-$Killing vector fields on Riemannian manifolds](http://www.emis.de/journals/BJGA/v13n1/B13-1.htm)
[$2-$Killing vector fields on warped product manifolds](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0129167X15500652)

Comment: What is $\rho$?

Comment: It is a smooth real fuction defined on $M$.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier I have added two links to two articles considering the study of $2-$Killing vector fields.

Comment: Why the algebraic geometry tag? And have you computed something like $(d/dt)^2 \phi_t^*g$? I guess up to some lower order terms they will agree.

Comment: Back of the envelope calculation gives me $$(\mathcal{L}_X \mathcal{L}_X g) (U,V) = 2g(R(X,U)X,V) + 2g(\nabla_U X, \nabla_V X) + g(U,\nabla_V\nabla_X X) + g(\nabla_U \nabla_X X, V).$$

Comment: @VítTuček Your formula seems to be right. I got the following $$(\mathcal{L}_X \mathcal{L}_X g) (U,V) = g(\nabla_X\nabla_UX-\nabla_{[X,U]}X,V) + g(\nabla_X\nabla_VX-\nabla_{[X,V]}X,U)+2g(\nabla_U X, \nabla_V X) $$. But I wand to interpret these part, is it a kind of symmetry.

Comment: @VítTuček How to start studying the geometry of manifolds admitting these vector fields?

Comment: @FanZheng I did not, but I will try and I hope they agree. In this case this expression will measure how fast the metric changes, am I right?

Comment: @SamehShenawy I would guess it's kind of a second variation of the metric.

Comment: @FanZheng I am trying to understand. I have considered $w=\mathcal{L}_Xg$ as a tensor of rank $2$ and then apply the definition of Lie derivative of tensors on $w$.